# How to create conditional statement before a specific year

Tags: java, date

I have a method that should process a string only if it is before a specific year. However I don't seem to be able to get the thing to work - I don't think the comparison is being done correctly. Can someone show me how the comparison is done for just years. If `Joda time` is better can you also show how (rather than tell me to just use joda time)

The string is in the UK date format eg `16/02/2006`

My code:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy"); 
Date yearOnReport = df.parse(startDateString);
Date threshold = df.parse("2006")
if (yearOnReport<threshold){
...\\Do some stuff
}
```

Comment: Threshold is not the correct word i think because threshold is inclusive like <=. Use tooLate instead because it is exclusive like <.

Comment: Are you using Java 8? If so you should use the `java.time` classes which are derived from Joda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java 8, use a [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) and a [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html):

```
String startDateString = "16/02/2006";

DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu");
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(startDateString, dateTimeFormatter);
if (localDate.getYear() < 2006) {
    // code here
}
```

If you need to support older versions of Java, use [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) and [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
String startDateString = "16/02/2006";

SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(startDateString);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(date);
if (calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) < 2006) {
    // code here
}
```

In Java 7, you can do it the Java 8 way by getting the backport of the new `java.time` API from the [ThreeTen project](http://www.threeten.org/).
Advantage: Code will work when later upgrading to Java 8, without needing an extra library in Java 8.

Alternatively, add [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) and use its [`LocalDate`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) and [`DateTimeFormat`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html):

```
String startDateString = "16/02/2006";

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
LocalDate localDate = formatter.parseLocalDate(startDateString);
if (localDate.getYear() < 2006) {
    // code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare Dates with relational operators.

You can use the [Date#compareTo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#compareTo(java.util.Date)) method.

Comment: What about if (yearOnReport.before(threshold)){}

Comment: You can use that method as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use `before()` logical operators only work on primitive types.

This:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy"); 
Date yearOnReport = df.parse(startDateString);
Date threshold = df.parse("2006")
if (yearOnReport<threshold){
...\\Do some stuff
}
```

Should be this:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); 
Date yearOnReport = df.parse(startDateString);
Date threshold = df.parse("2006")
if (yearOnReport.before(threshold)){
...\\Do some stuff
}
```

Comment: Unless the OP is using Java 8, in which case s/he should use the builtin `java.time` classes derived from/inspired by Joda.

Comment: Parse error, because *"The string is in the UK date format eg `16/02/2006`"*.